# Visual Studio output window with just my logs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

It's there a way in Visual Studio 2015 to make the output window to write just the messages that I send thru System.Diagnostics?

I'm printing debug messages but there's too mucho bloat, I just want to see mine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you filtered the Output window to reduce the flood of message that get printed?  Right-click and you should see a set like this:

[image: Output window message filters]

Comment: Ffffff... there's a prominent dropdown that says "Show output from" and there's no option for program output. Right clicking never came to my mind. Thanks.

Comment: The dropdown is for different output sources (debugging, build, tests, or anything else - it's easily extensible), but within the debugging context, these are the options available. :)

Comment: Is there any way to further customize/extend this, so you could have output categories, and filter to see only them?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank I don't know of a way to further customize the Debug contents in the Output window, but you could create your own output pane and put anything into that.  For example, the Build output is separate from the Debug output.  But you'd have to channel everything into your pane that way.

Comment: How do you make a custom output pane? I've never been able to find a way to do that either!

Answer (score 6):

I've wanted to filter my Visual Studio output into my own custom categories for many years. Eventually I decided to write an extension to do it. If you're interested, you can check it out at [niahtextfilter.com](https://www.niahtextfilter.com).

Here's an idea of what it does:
[image]

Comment: Is it language independent or just for c++ ?

Comment: Almost entirely language independent - it simply works off the output in the VS output window. However, there are a couple of additional/optional features that require some code in your app - I provide C++ and C# samples for these on my website, but they're small & simple enough to port to any language I think. And if there was demand for a particular language, I could add code samples in other languages myself. Those additional/optional features are: more accurate timestamps, and separation of debug output by process ID when debugging multiple instances at once.

Comment: Cool (i just need c#) ... will have a look at it in a free minute.

Comment: This looks great, sadly nowadays I've been working 100% with web front-end. Some day I'll do backend again.